# File explorer in Android like Windows Explorer

Tags: android, widget

I want to develop a file explorer application for Android device for that I would like develop a file explorer like `Windows Explorer` kind of thing to browse folders and files of `phone` and `SD card`. Is it possible to do like that. If yes then how to start it in android ICS. Is there any tutorial or document?

I want to develop this application on android 4.0 based tablet. Because the tablet will contain enough space so for that I chosen windows-explorer thing to for File explorer

Comment: Astro file manager... for example

Comment: @Zoombie : Thanks for ur rply. I will try to see the Astro file manager

Answer (score 0):

The basis for any such app is java.io.File. Using that, you can list files and folders and get information about them.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

There are lots of file browsers available from the Android market, so make sure you are building it for the right reasons ... i.e., for your own personal growth and experience, but not to provide something that does not already exist in many forms.